# Is there a way to get coordinates of cropping via Rmagick after cropping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, crop, rmagick, jcrop

I have a `RubyOnRails` application.
I use carrierwave for images uploading and jcrop for cropping.

I have two images: original and cropped image.
But I have no saved coordinates of this cropping (`crop_z`, `crop_y`, `crop_w` and `crop_h`)

Is there any way to get cropping coordinates via `Rmagick` or something another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general I don't think the crop coordinates are recorded in the image metadata. (They're saved in the metadata in the Magick format but very few people save their images in that format.) However, you may have some luck detecting the position of the cropped image in the original using the [find_similar_region](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#find_similar_region) method. Pass the cropped image as the target argument. If this method finds a region in the original that matches the target it returns the x- and y-offset of the region. The width and height of the region, of course, are the width and height of the cropped image.